# ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow' when creating a .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a .exe with pyinstaller, tensorflow and tkinter, my program works fine when I run it with python.

My environment is a conda with python 3.6.10, Windows 10, my tensorflow is 2.1, and pyinstaller 3.6

When I create the .exe and execute it, its returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from UI.main_ui import main_ui
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "UI\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from UI.main_ui import main_ui
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "UI\main_ui.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Modelo.src.color_detection.classify import classify
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "Modelo\src\color_detection\classify.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
  File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\projectname\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'
[9428] Failed to execute script main
```

I've tried to include a hook file in a additional-hooks-dir:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all


def hook(hook_api):
    packages = [
        'tensorflow',
        'tensorflow_core',
        'astor'
    ]
    for package in packages:
        datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(package)
        hook_api.add_datas(datas)
        hook_api.add_binaries(binaries)
        hook_api.add_imports(*hiddenimports)
```

but nothing changed

Comment: Do you see any warning message during pyinstaller execution?

Comment: I'm also stuck in a similar problem on ubuntu 18.04 and it looks like PyInstaller doesn't work with TensorFlow 2.1.

Comment: I receive the following error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: from tensorflow import * can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker managed to solve this problem.
We created a .py passing a .spec as paremeter to the PyInstaller.**main**.run,
something like that

```
PyInstaller.__main__.run([<name>.spec, --clean])
```

and passed the modules as parameters to the hiddenimportsList on the .spec file

```
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

block_cipher = None

dataList=collect_data_files('tensorflow_core')

hiddenimportsList=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'tensorflow']
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("tensorflow_core")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("opencv-python")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("numpy")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("scikit-image")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("imutils")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("scikit-learn")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("openpyxl")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("cv2")
hiddenimportsList+=collect_submodules("sklearn")

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=dataList,
             hiddenimports=hiddenimportsList,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name=<name>,
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False, icon='<icon>.ico')
```